# Image highlight information from other page in uwp C#

Tags: c#, button, uwp, live

I want to send from one window to another that this grid is selected and that it will be highlighted on other window. My code runs thru the images and stops at one and is then "Highlighted", but i want that on other page, `Datapage`, to be highlighted too. `Datapage` has same images as `Filepage`.

```
public void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    index++;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        ((Grid)gMainGrid.FindName($"g" + i)).BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    }
    ((Grid)gMainGrid.FindName($"g{index}")).BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    if (index == random)
    {
        Timer.Stop();
        SpinnerSecond.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        DataWatch.valueWatch = random;
        RollKnop.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

This is what I want but thru a button click, I want a live update?

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ((Grid)gMainGrid2.FindName($"g{ DataWatch.valueWatch}")).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGoldenrodYellow);
}
```

Comment: **sorry for bad languege**

Comment: Could you explain the mean of  `live update` ?

Comment: So when timer stops from other page, that it take the data of the random and saves it and sends to other page and gets higlighted

Comment: You could call `Navigate` with parameter  method when timer stop.